# Why java.lang.Class doesn't implement java.lang.reflect.Member interface?

Tags: java, reflection, interface, sdk, internals

I'm working on a Package Browser in browser in Java and trying to write a generic method which can handle all members of the class - basically collecting string representation of them, choosing an image and displaying it in a tree view.

For all [Members](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Member.html) (Field, Method, Constructor) it has been working great - they all have `getName()` and `isSynthetic()` which allows me to treat them in the same way because that's all I need.

But [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) is special - **even though it has all the methods of that interface, it doesn't technically implement it!**.

And to handle it I need a special-case-method or do an `instanceof` checks, which is not very clean.

So, i guess, this is more of a philosophical question - why is that? Because classes are not considered to be "proper" members of classes and instead are nested? Or because of something else?

Please shine the light on this topic!

I tried to treat objects of type `Class<?>` as if they implemented interface `Member`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer should be found in `getDeclaringClass`.

From `Member`:

> Returns the Class object representing the class or interface that declares the member or constructor represented by this Member.

From `Class`:

> If the class or interface represented by this Class object is a member of another class, returns the Class object representing the class in which it was declared. This method returns null if this class or interface is not a member of any other class. If this Class object represents an array class, a primitive type, or void,then this method returns null.

That possible `null` is the main difference. Instances of `Member` are not allowed to return `null`, instances of `Class` are. If Oracle would change the specification of `Member.getDeclaringClass` to allow `null` return values, that could break existing code. They can fix those occurrences in the JDK itself, but not in third party code.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect `Class` to implement `Member`?

A class, by default, is a top level class and not a nested one. Thus, it's not a member of any other class.

What I'm trying to say is that a `class B` is only a `Member` if it's a nested class declared in some `class A`. But then it doesn't make sense that `A` also implements `Member`.

I am not good with words today, I hope I got my point communicated clearly.

Comment: But it has all the methods, and can answer all the same questions that Member can - I can just ask, for a specific instance of Class<?>, what is yours declaring class - and that will give me the result that's different from my own class (if it's the nested class) or null (if it's not nested). 
EDIT: By that I mean, that a Class _can_ be treated as a Member, if you squint your eyes just a bit. It passes [duck test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) in my book.

Comment: @AndriyMykhaylyk You are correct, but that's not a good reason to implement `Member`. Type hierarchies have to make sense semantically, implementing the same methods isn't the only requirement. Is a `Class` always a `Member`? No, so it shouldn't implement that interface. However, it might make sense to have an `InnerClass` that extends `Class` and implements `Member`.

Comment: @AndriyMykhaylyk you should not only look at syntax but also semantics. Yes, `Class` has all the methods, but it doesn't follow the _specification_ for `getDeclaringClass`. See my answer for why not.